# Empty Shared with me Folder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to Empty `Share with me folder` How can I empty It is My Code and I am using Google Drive V3 .

```
service.Permissions.Delete(PermissionID, fileId).Execute();
service.Files.Delete(fileId).Execute();
```

Both line gives a permission 403 error.

If I delete MyDrive file that time Second line he worked fine but Shared With me Folder not Deleted

Comment: are you using a service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you need to remember is that Share with me is not a file you actually own that is why this didn't work.

> service.Files.Delete(fileId).Execute();

First Get a list of all files in Share with me folder.

```
var request = service.Files.List();
request.Q = "(sharedWithMe = true)";
request.Fields = "*";
var results = request.Execute();
```

Find the file you wish to delete:

```
var myfile = results.Files.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower().Equals("receipt.pdf")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now find the permissions on that file associated with the current authenticated user:

```
var per = myfile.Permissions.Where(a => a.EmailAddress.ToLower().Equals("xxxxx@gmail.com")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Delete the permissions from the mail file.

```
service.Permissions.Delete(myfile.Id, per.Id).Execute();
```

I tested it and it worked.   You can just run the initial request though a loop and delete everything if you wish.

**Note:** This does not appear to work in all cases. I have a file on my Google drive that was shared with me by what appears to be a service account.  I have no permissions on the file there for i cant remove my access.    I am still digging.

Comment: Return Permission Error

Comment: Are you using a service account?  I was able to do it with readonly permissions.   Using Oauth2 Here is the full source i used https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/6e3b76fa3e9a2d8d72d96fe7f1d71297